# How to use ruby 2.0.0 is a single rails app

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-2.0

I originally had ruby 1.9.3 installed on my computer as the only ruby version.  I would like to make an app for Heroku which requires ruby 2.0.0.  I just successfully installed ruby-2.0.0-p353 onto my computer and would like to use that for a single app.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a Ruby version in your Gemfile by adding: `ruby "2.0.0"`

For more info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Answer (score 0):

If you use [rvm](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) you can have default version 1.9.3, and for any project set version 2.0.0 in .ruby-version or Gemfile

See https://rvm.io/workflow/projects